# Get Decile of Values and # of records between deciles Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that looks like this

| User ID | Income |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.00 |
| 2 | 5.00 |
| 1 | 7.00 |
| 3 | 10.00 |
| 4 | 80.00 |
| 1 | 40.00 |
| 5 | 7.00 |
| 6 | 4.00 |

I need a Presto SQL query that breaks the range of "Income" {eg.4.00-80.00} up into deciles irrespective of frequency of that "Income" value. I also need the # of unique "User ID" that falls beneath that decile (eg. 10th percentile -> X users, 20th percentile Y users).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the decile for each user-income, and then join the cte with itself (to account for the repeated users, since count distinct over() is not allowed in Presto).

```
WITH user_deciles_cte AS(
    SELECT  user_id,
            NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY income) AS deciles
    FROM table
),
join_users_and_deciles_cte AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT dec.deciles,
                    users.user_id
    FROM user_deciles_cte dec
    LEFT JOIN user_deciles_cte users
    ON users.deciles <= dec.deciles
)
SELECT deciles,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users
FROM join_users_and_deciles_cte
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```